# Can I control what caches are flushed via "Flush all caches"?

Tags: caching

I use the module [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) and anytime I click "Flush all caches" it deletes all the cached pages already built. Is there any way to make "Flush all caches" to flush all cache instead of the Boost-created **.html.gz** cached pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [admin menu module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) you can selectively target which cache to flush by hovering over the the *Flush all cache* menu under the home icon. The *Class registry* and *Page and else* will wipe out the Boost cache, but everything else will leave it intact.

[image]

Comment: And if I want to clear all but these two? (Assuming it's possible or effective)...

Comment: Not sure. I only know this from experience. There's probably a programmatic way of doing this through the Drupal API, but I'm not familiar with it..